# Como evitar que o Double transforme um número grande em expoenencial?

Tags: android

Eu tenho um sistema de cálculos no meu app, uso o TextWatcher e quando calculo um número grande e salvo, quando retorno o valor, ele vem em exponencial (123e+23). Já tentei usar bigDecimal mas deu o mesmo erro. Alguém sabe o que pode ser? agradeço desde já.

Comment: Isso é a notação científica, utilizada exatamente para mostrar o número de uma maneira mais enxuta. Você tem certeza que quer mostrar o número: 12300000000000000000000000?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma das maneiras de fazer isso é utilizar a própria classe String.

```
String.format("%.0f", new BigDecimal("123e+23"));
```

A saída desse código é:

```
12300000000000000000000000
```

Outra maneira usando só a classe BigDecimal é:

```
new BigDecimal("123e+23").toPlainString();
```

Produzirá a mesma saída.

Entretanto, deve haver um caso bem específico para mostrar um número com tantos dígitos para o usuário.

O número 123e+23 está na notação científica. É o mesmo que escrever 123 x 10^23 ou 1,23 x 10^25 ou 12300000000000000000000000.

Comment: Então, quase funcionou, o problema é que tenho que gravar em Double no banco e quando converto essa String para double volta o exponencial. Mas obrigado, vou ver o que posso fazer aqui.

Comment: e se vc fizer assim: String.format("%.0f",Double.valueOf("12300000000000000000000000")). Veja que primeiro estou transformando uma String em um Double (usando o valueOf). O resultado disso é um Double que é impresso na notação científica. Depois disso, esse Double é passado para o format do String.

Comment: Para eu gravar no preciso usar um "parseDouble", daí volta a notação científica.

Comment: Vc tá dizendo que no seu banco de dados tá sendo gravado como notação científica?

Comment: sim, quando vou gravar no banco eu tenho que usar o parseDouble, daí grava com a notação científica.

Comment: Qual é o tipo de campo que está no seu banco de dados?

Comment: no meu banco, é real (sqlite) mas estou usando getters e setters de uma biblioteca já pré-definida onde é um Double para este atributo. Tenho que gravar como double não posso fugir.

Comment: Acho que vc está fazendo confusão. Não sei como você está vendo esse dado gravado no SQLite, mas, provavelmente, o programa que você está utilizando pra ver está fazendo essa conversão pra notação científica e você está tendo a impressão de que o dado foi gravado assim.

Comment: Antes de gravar eu printei para teste, só de colocar o parseDouble já fica com a notação, Depois de um certo número, 7 ou 8 o Double usa a notação científica, acho que não posso fazer nada, mas vlw pela ajuda Cantoni.

Comment: desculpa a insistência em tentar te ajudar.. sou assim. :-) Veja bem, você printou no JAVA, mas o dado foi gravado no SQLite. Não significa que o dado foi gravado como impresso no Java. Isso pouco importa na verdade. O importante é que você, ao recuperar o dado, formate a representação, se necessário.